# Intercept pager events XPages

Tags: xpages, xpages-ssjs

I have a bean that has a `List<Person> people` property.  This holds custom POJO objects `Person` that are populated from a notes view.

The list is then surface in an xpage using a custom `repeat` control

I have tested this with a hundred or so records and performance is fine, but when testing with larger datasets > 10000 records, performance drops.

I have an idea that I can lazy load the `people` by only loading the first page (say 30 records) `bean.loadData(0, 30)` and then load the next set, when the user uses the pager associated with the repeat control.

How do I intercept the pager click to call the `loadData(startRow, endRow)` method?  Or is there another approach I should/could use that still makes use of the bean.

Answer (score 1):

There is at least one way I know to do that, but unfortunately it requires a bit of work. I have created a complete `DataSource` of my own. If a DataSource's Model class extends `TabularDataModel`, it works seamlessly with the Pager control. IBM's `DominoViewDataModel` class works that way.

The complete procedure is a bit long, but was explained in this (highly interesting) LotusSphere 2011 session: http://www.slideshare.net/NotesSensei/show107-the-datasource-session-take-xpages-data-boldly-where-no-xpages-data-has-been-taken-before